# Dynamically select DataTemplate based on tables residing in strongly typed dataset

Tags: wpf, dataset, datatemplate

I have a strongly typed DataSet with a number of tables and I'd like to be able to automatically/dynamically render a specific DataTemplate when displaying data from any of the tables. Now, what should be specified when declaring the DataTemplate like below:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:<...what do I need to specify here???...>}>
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Say that i have specified

```
xmlns:c="RiskManager.Models.RiskManagerModel"
```

and in that namespace I have an "enterpriseDataTable".

I'm not able get this working so I wonder what Im doing wrong here...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is `RiskManagerModel` part of the namespace name or is it the class name? if it's your class name maybe try having `xmlns:c="clr-namespace:RiskManager.Models"` and then <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:RiskManagerModel}">`

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more explicit so here it comes: namespace is "RiskManager.Models.RiskManagerModel" and the row-type I'd like to map to (DataType) is "RiskManagerModel.enterpriseRow". Many thanks for helping me!

Comment: Hmmm, further investigation shows that the enterpriseRow is nested within RiskManagerModel and intellisense tells me that nested types are not allowed in the DataType declaration. Thought it would be wise to tell you.

Comment: I'm still confused. Is `enterpriseDataTable` a Class Name or a variable name. If it's a variable name you cant set it as the DataContext use it's Type(which is class name) as your x:Type for DataContext

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The class I'm trying to rendern dynamically is "enterpriseRow" which in turn is a nested type in "RiskManager.Models.RiskManagerModel".

Comment: ok can you please post your exact "class" structure by editing your question please. just forget abt the contents inside the classes, but just post the code related to class declarations and the namespaces they fall under(your Model, the variable of type enterpriseRow and also it's own class declaration with it's namespace if different). This shouldn't be as complicated as what it's turning out to be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29918/discussion-between-viv-and-user1297653)